# I am trying to improve the performance of an Oracle SQL that is finding the differences between two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, informatica

I have two Oracle tables and I am doing an UNION between them to find out the difference in the data stored in those two tables but when I run the query in SQL Developer then the query is too slow and I am using the same query in Informatica and its throughput is less too.

TABLE 1: W_SALES_INVOICE_LINE_FS EBS(NET_AMT, 
   INVOICED_QTY,
    CREATED_ON_DT,
    CHANGED_ON_DT, 
    INTEGRATION_ID,
     'EBS' AS SOURCE_NAME)

TABLE 2: W_SALES_INVOICE_LINE_F DWH (NET_AMT, 
   INVOICED_QTY,
    CREATED_ON_DT,
    CHANGED_ON_DT, 
    INTEGRATION_ID,
     'EBS' AS SOURCE_NAME)

I am attaching the query with the question:

```
SELECT EBS.NET_AMT, 
nvl(EBS.INVOICED_QTY,
case nvl(EBS.NET_AMT,0) when 0 then EBS.INVOICED_QTY
else -1 end) INVOICED_QTY,
EBS.CREATED_ON_DT,
 EBS.CHANGED_ON_DT, 
     EBS.INTEGRATION_ID,
 'EBS' AS SOURCE_NAME
 FROM
 W_SALES_INVOICE_LINE_FS EBS
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT  INTEGRATION_ID FROM      W_SALES_INVOICE_LINE_F    DWH
  WHERE EBS.INTEGRATION_ID = DWH.INTEGRATION_ID)
UNION
 SELECT DWH.NET_AMT,
  DWH.INVOICED_QTY, 
  DWH.CREATED_ON_DT,
  DWH.CHANGED_ON_DT, 
  DWH.INTEGRATION_ID,
 'DWH' AS SOURCE_NAME
   FROM
 W_SALES_INVOICE_LINE_F DWH
 where DWH.IS_POS = 'N' and
  not exists (SELECT  INTEGRATION_ID FROM W_SALES_INVOICE_LINE_FS EBS
 WHERE EBS.INTEGRATION_ID = DWH.INTEGRATION_ID);
```

Let me know if you want to see the explain plan. Can someone tell me how to improve the performance or let me know if the issues is with something else and not with the above query!
[image: SQL EXPLAIN PLAN]

Comment: `Union` and `Not Exists` can be performance killers.  Are you sure you need a`Union` here and can't use `Union All` instead?

Comment: Consider using `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` to avoid unnecesarry sort -> results of both parts of the query are always different because the last column `SOURCE_NAME` is either 'EBS' or 'DWH', but the database doesn't know this and must sort both results to perform the union.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not performing a `JOIN`, you are performing a `UNION`. You are performing subqueries however, and those may be slowing down the overall performance. You might change the `EXISTS` to `IN` which can take advantage of an index if it exists.

Try the following:

```
SELECT EBS.NET_AMT, 
nvl(EBS.INVOICED_QTY,
case nvl(EBS.NET_AMT,0) when 0 then EBS.INVOICED_QTY
else -1 end) INVOICED_QTY,
EBS.CREATED_ON_DT,
 EBS.CHANGED_ON_DT, 
     EBS.INTEGRATION_ID,
 'EBS' AS SOURCE_NAME
 FROM
 W_SALES_INVOICE_LINE_FS EBS
  WHERE EBS.INTEGRATION_ID NOT IN (
     SELECT  INTEGRATION_ID 
     FROM W_SALES_INVOICE_LINE_F
)
UNION ALL
 SELECT DWH.NET_AMT,
  DWH.INVOICED_QTY, 
  DWH.CREATED_ON_DT,
  DWH.CHANGED_ON_DT, 
  DWH.INTEGRATION_ID,
 'DWH' AS SOURCE_NAME
   FROM
 W_SALES_INVOICE_LINE_F DWH
 where DWH.IS_POS = 'N' 
 and DWH.INTEGRATION_ID not in (
     SELECT  INTEGRATION_ID 
     FROM W_SALES_INVOICE_LINE_FS
  );
```

Also, as mentioned by others in comments, a `UNION ALL` might be more appropriate.

Also, you could try using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` which, if you do have an index, is a more explicit way of doing the above. I don't have access to my oracle from my current location to try an explain plan, but the above and below may actually be optimized similarly.

```
SELECT EBS.NET_AMT, 
    Nvl(EBS.INVOICED_QTY,
        CASE Nvl(EBS.NET_AMT, 0) WHEN 0 
        THEN EBS.INVOICED_QTY
        ELSE -1 END
    ) AS INVOICED_QTY,
    EBS.CREATED_ON_DT,
    EBS.CHANGED_ON_DT, 
    EBS.INTEGRATION_ID,
    'EBS' AS SOURCE_NAME
FROM W_SALES_INVOICE_LINE_FS EBS
LEFT OUTER JOIN W_SALES_INVOICE_LINE_F DWH
ON DWH.INTEGRATION_ID = EBS.INTEGRATION_ID
WHERE DWH.INTEGRATION_ID IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT DWH.NET_AMT,
    DWH.INVOICED_QTY, 
    DWH.CREATED_ON_DT,
    DWH.CHANGED_ON_DT, 
    DWH.INTEGRATION_ID,
    'DWH' AS SOURCE_NAME
FROM W_SALES_INVOICE_LINE_F DWH
LEFT OUTER JOIN W_SALES_INVOICE_LINE_FS EBS
ON EBS.INTEGRATION_ID = DWH.INTEGRATION_ID
WHERE EBS.INTEGRATION_ID IS NULL
AND DWH.IS_POS = 'N'
;
```

Could you provide a brief description of the tables in your question? How many (approximately) records are in each table? Do you have any indexes? Are any of the fields calculated/derived? When you do an explain plan on these or your original query, where does it show the bottleneck?

Comment: I have changed the question based on your correction. I am testing the query on my DB and it promptly returns the default number of rows ie:50. I am trying to get the count of all the rows and it is still running and taking a lot of time which means it is still having a bad performance? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Do you have an index on the `INTEGRATION_ID` columns on your tables?

Comment: Yes I have created a BITMAP INDEX on both the INTEGRATION_ID columns.

Comment: ROW COUNT Of the tables:
W_SALES_INVOICE_LINE_FS - 800,000

W_SALES_INVOICE_LINE_F - 4,000,000

Comment: If `INTEGRATION_ID` is unique I would use `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ...` or you have a VERY high cardinality (and it is more ratio of uniqueness to record count that is important instead of just cardinality), then I would use `CREATE INDEX ...` instead of a `CREATE BITMAP INDEX ...`.

Comment: There are no other indexes on the remaining other columns apart from INTEGRATION_ID for both the tables.

Comment: What I mean is that a `BITMAP INDEX` may not be ideal for your situation, Is `INTEGRATION_ID` a unique column? What is the ratio of distinct `INTEGRATION_ID` values to the total number of records is the table?

Comment: Yes I am changing them to UNIQUE index. INTEGRATION_ID consists of UNIQUE IDs. Throughout the table the INTEGRATION_ID is unique. I have also attached the EXPLAIN_PLAN for the query in the question on the top.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100670/discussion-between-dilip-and-gmiley).

Answer (score 1):

Not exists and not in statements can often be the performance bottleneck. A performance trick to get round this is to use a LEFT OUTER JOIN with a clause stating the second table column is null I.e. there is no matching row. So try:

```
SELECT EBS.NET_AMT, 
nvl(EBS.INVOICED_QTY,
case nvl(EBS.NET_AMT,0) when 0 then EBS.INVOICED_QTY
else -1 end) INVOICED_QTY,
EBS.CREATED_ON_DT,
 EBS.CHANGED_ON_DT, 
     EBS.INTEGRATION_ID,
 'EBS' AS SOURCE_NAME
 FROM
 W_SALES_INVOICE_LINE_FS EBS
 LEFT OUTER JOIN 
  W_SALES_INVOICE_LINE_F    DWH
  ON EBS.INTEGRATION_ID = DWH.INTEGRATION_ID
  WHERE DWH.INTEGRATION_ID IS NULL
UNION
 SELECT DWH.NET_AMT,
  DWH.INVOICED_QTY, 
  DWH.CREATED_ON_DT,
  DWH.CHANGED_ON_DT, 
  DWH.INTEGRATION_ID,
 'DWH' AS SOURCE_NAME
   FROM
 W_SALES_INVOICE_LINE_F DWH
 LEFT OUTER JOIN W_SALES_INVOICE_LINE_FS EBS
 ON EBS.INTEGRATION_ID = DWH.INTEGRATION_ID
 where EBS.INTEGRATION_ID IS NULL
 AND DWH.IS_POS = 'N'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are manually coding a full outer join which Oracle can do automatically for this sort of comparison tasks (and I would guess it might run quicker)

```
select
ebs.net_amt ebs_net_amt,
dwh.net_amt dwh_net_amt,
nvl(ebs.invoiced_qty,case nvl(ebs.net_amt,0) when 0 then ebs.invoiced_qty else -1 end) invoiced_qty_ebs,
dwh.invoiced_qty invoiced_qty_dwh,
ebs.created_on_dt ebs_created_on_dt,
dwh.created_on_dt dwh_created_on_dt,
ebs.changed_on_dt ebs_changed_on_dt,
dwh.changed_on_dt dwh_changed_on_dt,
nvl(ebs.integration_id,ebs.integration_id) integration_id,
case
when ebs.integration_id is not null and ebs.integration_id is not null and then 'EBS and DWH'
when dwh.integration_id is not null then 'EBS'
else 'DWH' 
end source_name
from
w_sales_invoice_line_fs ebs
full outer join
(select * from w_sales_invoice_line_f dwh where dwh.is_pos = 'N') dwh
on 
(ebs.integration_id = dwh.integration_id)
where
ebs.integration_id is null or dwh.integration_id is null --restrict to records missing on one side
```